# PayPal Integration HTTP Error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have PayPal integrated on my website. There's a form on my site which takes the customer to PayPal to finalise the payment then it returns them to my site. My site then sends a request back to PayPal with the transaction token for PDT so that I can run a few checks then auto-credit my customer's with the product they bought.

The system uses PHP and cURL to send process all this.

When I use: `"www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`

Along with the sandbox credentials everything works fine, everything.

Once I change it all to `"www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`

It does not work, My code tells me that the request fails.
My Code:

```
$pp_hostname = "www.paypal.com";

        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

        $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
        $auth_token = "#######-hashed_out_here-########";
        $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        //set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
        //if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$res){
                $this->twig->error("Request failed.");
        }else{
            $lines = explode("\n", $res);
            $keyarray = array();
            if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
                for ($i='1'; $i<count($lines);$i++){
                    $test = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
                    if(empty($test[1])){
                        $keyarray[urldecode($test[0])] = '';
                    }else{
                        $keyarray[urldecode($test[0])] = urldecode($test[1]);
                    }
                }
                //give product
            } else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
                $this->twig->error('Transaction failed!');
            }
        }
```

Not sure why I'm having a problem so I don't know how to go about fixing.
My PayPal Account is set up as Business, has PDT and IPN turned on as well as Auto-Return

It appears that I'm receiving HTTP Error, but which I cannot say, if I log the curl_error it simply says " " and if I log the curl_errno I get 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed. It was due to my server not having the ssl certificates installed, once I did so it worked fine.